# XUL's textbox and jQuery, how to retrieve value?

Tags: jquery, xul

I've a XUL document with a textbox:

```
<textbox id="prod_text" />
```

I tried to retrieve the value that was manually added on it using jQuery, in this way:

```
Firebug.Console.log($("textbox#prod_text").attr('value'));
```

But it doesn't work! It returns an empty value...
What is wrong?

Edit: I'm working in a Firefox extension... that's where my functions was associated to an event. I'm trying to access data in a XUL document...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using jquery's "val" method?

http://api.jquery.com/val/

This should get the value of the text box. It can also be used to set the value (if you so desire).

Comment: I've tried this: 
Firebug.Console.log($("textbox#prod_text").val()) - but again, I receive an empty message in Firebug...

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why, but in this way it worked (adding an hidden label, synchronized with the textbox):

```
<textbox id="prod_text" onkeyup="var t = document.getElementById('prod_text_hid'); t.value = value;"/>
<label value="label" hidden="true" id="prod_text_hid"/>
```

And then:

```
Firebug.Console.log($("#prod_text_hid").attr('value'));
```

...returns the right value!!!

Do you have an idea of the reason? It's an ugly solution, but it works... :-(